# For each row in a dataframe, return a list of columns that are NaN. But not all columns, only those in a given list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking at building out some logging of errors and trying to catch null values in specific columns.
Essentially, I want to go from a dataframe and list of columns, to then output a dataframe with a column containing which of those columns from the list are null for each row. Note, I will also be doing this for negative values etc.
Example:

```
columns_list = ['A','B','D']
```

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 22 | 1231 | -121 |
| 2022-01-02 | 11 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-03 | NaN | 52 | 12 | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | 11 | 27 | NaN | 3434 |

The following code will give the following output but I want to be able to use columns_list to not have column C being returned in X:

```
df['X']= df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.isnull()].index), axis=1)
```

| Date | A | B | C | D | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | 11 | NaN | NaN | NaN | B,C,D |
| 2022-01-03 | NaN | 52 | 12 | 0 | A |
| 2022-01-04 | 11 | 27 | NaN | 3434 | C |

Thanking you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subset your columns:

```
df['X']= df[columns_list].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.isnull()].index), axis=1)
```